# load multiple .dta files selecting variables

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iteration

I have multiple Stata files I would like to read as separate dataframes, selecting specific variables from each.

The files are:

```
a_hhresp.dta
b_hhresp.dta
c_hhresp.dta
d_hhresp.dta
etc.
```

The variables I want from each are:

```
a_hidp, a_fihhmnnet1_dv, a_ieqmoecd_dv
b_hidp, b_fihhmnnet1_dv, b_ieqmoecd_dv
etc.
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
hh1 <- read_dta("a_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("a_hidp", "a_fihhmnnet1_dv", "a_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh2 <- read_dta("b_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("b_hidp", "b_fihhmnnet1_dv", "b_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh3 <- read_dta("c_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("c_hidp", "c_fihhmnnet1_dv", "c_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh4 <- read_dta("d_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("d_hidp", "d_fihhmnnet1_dv", "d_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh5 <- read_dta("e_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("e_hidp", "e_fihhmnnet1_dv", "e_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh6 <- read_dta("f_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("f_hidp", "f_fihhmnnet1_dv", "f_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh7 <- read_dta("g_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("g_hidp", "g_fihhmnnet1_dv", "g_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh8 <- read_dta("h_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("h_hidp", "h_fihhmnnet1_dv", "h_ieqmoecd_dv"))
hh9 <- read_dta("i_hhresp.dta", col_select=c("i_hidp", "i_fihhmnnet1_dv", "i_ieqmoecd_dv"))
```

This is of course poor form, unnecessary copy-pasting -- it should be possible to do it via iteration of a line or two.  And if I can work out how to do it for this component, then perhaps I can use what I've learned for doing other tasks more efficiently as well.

I had in mind to use lapply (having first created a list of the files) -- but I don't see a way to select the columns at the initial stage.

I'm trying to avoid writing separate lines for tasks such as these -- thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT**

This is a large panel dataset ("Understanding Society" in the UK), with 9 waves (so far) and multiple files per wave. What I've described above corresponds to the household-level data.

After creating a list ("listhh"), I can lapply:

```
dfhh <- lapply(listhh, function(x) read_dta(x))
```

This works, but it takes all the variables -- so, the list of dataframes is very large.

When using lapply, I don't see anything that works with the col_select option -- because the variable prefixes are different for each file.

I can load all the files with lapply (containing all the variables), I can then turn it into a dataframe:

```
dfhh <- rbindlist(dfhh, fill = TRUE)
```

And I can then select only the columns I want:

```
dfhh %<>% select(grep("([a-z])_hidp", names(dfhh)), grep("([a-z])_fihhmnnet1_dv", names(dfhh)), grep("([a-z])_ieqmoecd_dv", names(dfhh)))
```

This works.  But when it comes to the individual-level files, everything is *much* larger.  When I try the same approach with the individual files, I get a "fatal error" and have to restart R.

It would be better to select the columns when reading in the data...

**FURTHER EDIT**

I think it's still better to read the files into separate dataframes.  I have to merge the household data with the individual data, using a wave-specific key (for Wave A, the key is: by="a_hidp").  If I have one dataframe containing all the household data, there is no longer a unique key -- I now have a_hidp, b_hidp, c_hidp, etc.)  I think I need 9 separate household-level dataframes, and 9 corresponding individual-level dataframes.  Merge within the waves, then join the waves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally worked out how to do this properly.  The following code works, loading all of the relevant datasets, selecting the variables I want and extracting the dataframes from the list (having assigned names to the elements of the list):

```
#create list
listhh <- list.files("path", pattern = "*_hhresp.dta")

#read the files
uh <- lapply(listhh, read_dta)

#select variables:
uh <- lapply(uh, function(x) x%>% select(ends_with("_hidp"),
                                         ends_with("_fihhmnnet1_dv"),
                                         ends_with("_ieqmoecd_dv")))

#name the list elements:
names(uh) <- gsub("\\.dta$", "", listhh)

#extract the individual dataframes from the list
list2env(uh, .GlobalEnv)
```

Thanks to David for getting me going on this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your data/inputs (maybe you can provide some more context, e.g., your `lapply` code), usually I would solve these kinds of problems like so

```r
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files("some-path", pattern = "*.dta$", full.name = TRUE)

all_data <- map_dfr(files, read_dta)
```

`map_dfr` is like a `lapply` call, but returns a data.frame (`df`) which consists of the row-binds (`r` in the dfr).

### Edit

`lapply` or `map_*` allow additional arguments to be passed, i.e.,

```r
foo <- function(times, text) {
  paste(rep(text, times), collapse = ", ")
}

foo(3, "hello")
#> [1] "hello, hello, hello"

# notice: text="val" given in lapply
lapply(1:3, foo, text = "val")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "val"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "val, val"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "val, val, val"

library(purrr)
map_chr(1:3, foo, text = "val")
#> [1] "val"           "val, val"      "val, val, val"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So in your case, you can have the following:

```r
cols <- c("a_hidp", "a_fihhmnnet1_dv", "a_ieqmoecd_dv")

data <- map_dfr(files, read_dta, col_select = cols)

# usually also a good version, which creates a new column with the filename
data <- map(files, read_dta, col_select = cols) %>%
     bind_rows(.id = "file")
```

#### Edit 2

Also, have a look at [`ends_with()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html). Your selection code can be simplified to

```r
dfhh %>% 
    select(
        ends_with("_hidp",
        ends_with("_fihhmnnet1_dv"),
        ends_with("_ieqmoecd_dv")
    )
```

Comment: Thank you again.  The difficulty is that the list of "cols" will only work with the files from the first wave.  In the file a_hhresp.dta, the variables all have the prefix a_, as in a_hidp.  But in the file b_hhresp.dta, the variables all have the prefix b_, as in b_hidp.  This is a core aspect of what I've been struggling with: how to use wildcards with filenames and variable/column-names so that I can iterate....

Comment: If there is a hardcoded logic to it, you could try to pass the variable names without the prefixes, and then add the prefixes within a function and then merge the data as you wish.